# Pod exceeding persistent volume capacity in minikube

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-storage, minikube, persistent-volumes

I am creating persistent volume with capacity of 50Mi in minikube. Pod claims it But when size of content increases beyond 50Mi and no error. Is there issue with kubernetes or minikube.? or this is because I am not using fixed sized volume i-e (azure disk etc.)

[Please find attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQoMC.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error, this is by design. These PVs in minigube are larger and kubernetes is not responsible in any way for setting storage quotas. A larger PV fulfills smaller PVC minimum requirements, that's it.

Comment: But I am setting persistent volume capacity to 50Mi. So, how can 50Mi volume can store more than 50Mi data.?

Comment: This capacity is only for PV matching to PVC, it will not enforce the limit at requested capacity. As the minikbe PVs are hostPath ones, they will be able to grow to the limit of local minikube space